# Removing facebook account from my desktop

Tags: windows-7, browser, facebook

How can I remove all trace of my ex-boyfriend's facebook account from my desktop. I do not use facebook myself but am constantly being asked to sign in to other sites via facebook. It's really annoying.

Comment: It sounds like this is simply a case of his past Facebook login history being prevalent within your web browser.  If that's the case, you should be able to refresh your web browser.  For example, [within Firefox you can easily clear your browsing history and cookies](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Privacy-and-security/Clear-browsing-history-and-cookies/ta-p/8602).  Every modern web browser has similar capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

From my point of view, the best way would be to delete all the browsing data. This way you will not need to go manually find and delete separate data entries.

1. For Google Chrome:

Settings->Show Advanced Settings->Clear browsing data...->Obliterate the following items from: The beginning of time->check all the check boxes->Clear browsing data

[image: Chrome clear browsing data setting]

2. For Mozilla Firefox:

Preferences->Privacy->Clear your recent history->Time range to clear: Everything->Details (check everything)->Clear Now

[image: Firefox clear history setting]

3. For Edge:

I use Mac, so I do not have access to Edge. But there is great guide from Microsoft on how to proceed with clearing history procedure: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/10607/microsoft-edge-view-delete-browser-history

It boils down to History->Clear all history->Check every box->Clear

[image: Edge clear histore setting]

4. For Safari:

History->Clear History...->Clear: all history->Clear History

[image: Safari clear history setting]

**Note!**

- Following this guide will remove all the data stored locally in your browser.
- The guide is applicable to the latest versions of the mentioned above browsers: Google Chrome 57.0.2987.98 (64-bit), Mozilla Firefox 52.0 (64-bit), Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0, Safari 10.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

A number of websites partner with facebook to provide logins via facebook. Some of that might not be on your end, but on their end.

Comment: Clearing all your cookies and browsing data should resolve this.

Comment: @music2myear : I was thinking that the OP was talking about the "login via facebook" tabs (like what stack overflow has!), and less so "Log in via facebook details are already loaded". Hard to tell with the amount of information given.